# How does more s character shorten bonds and strengthen bonds?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, bond, orbitals

I'm aware that having more s character means that electrons are in the lowest energy state (?) and very close to the positive atomic nucleus. But then what’s the connection between having electrons tightly bound to the nucleus and bond length and strength?

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152/why-is-the-2s-orbital-lower-in-energy-than-the-2p-orbital-when-the-electrons-in?rq=1